# Why is my rather trivial CUDA program erring with certain arguments?

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I made a simple CUDA program for practice. It simply copies over data from one array to another:

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import numpy as np
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule

# Global constants
N = 2**20 # size of array a
a = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
e = np.empty_like(a)
block_size_x = 512

# Instantiate block and grid sizes.
block_size = (block_size_x, 1, 1)
grid_size = (N / block_size_x, 1)

# Create the CUDA kernel, and run it.
mod = SourceModule("""
  __global__ void D2x_kernel(double* a, double* e, int N) {
    int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (tid > 0 && tid < N - 1) {
      e[tid] = a[tid];
    }
  }
""")
func = mod.get_function('D2x_kernel')
func(a, cuda.InOut(e), np.int32(N), block=block_size, grid=grid_size)
print str(e)
```

However, I get this error: `pycuda._driver.LogicError: cuLaunchKernel failed: invalid value`

When I get rid of the second argument `double* e` in my kernel function and invoke the kernel without the argument `e`, the error goes away. Why is that? What does this error mean?

Comment: That's weird that removing second argument helps. Have you tried explicitly specifying copying directions for your arrays: `func(cuda.In(a), cuda.Out(e), `...`)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `a` array does not exist in device memory, so I suspect that PyCUDA is ignoring (or otherwise handling) the first argument to your kernel invocation and only passing in `e` and `N`...so you get an error because the kernel was expecting three arguments and it has only received two.  Removing `double* e` from your kernel definition might eliminate the error message you're getting, but your kernel still won't work properly.

A quick fix to this should be to wrap `a` in a `cuda.In()` call, which instructs PyCUDA to copy `a` to the device before launching the kernel.  That is, your kernel launch line should be:

```
func(cuda.In(a), cuda.InOut(e), np.int32(N), block=block_size, grid=grid_size)
```

Edit: Also, do you realize that your kernel is not copying the first and last elements of `a` to `e`?  Your `if (tid > 0 && tid < N - 1)` statement is preventing that.  For the entire array, it should be `if (tid < N)`.